# How to add columns from a data frame to another based on a common column with different values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame both of them has a column"Country" common but in df1 it has 223 countries(means 223 rows) and in df2 it has only 188 countries(188 rows), both data frames have different columns values for ex.: df1 columns are(18) it contain the "Country", "Population", ....etc, and df2 column are(7) it contain "Country", "GNP", "Capital city",....etc.

I want to merge both data frames and match the values of columns in df2 according to the main column in df1 the "Country", so it adds the Population value from df2 for the exact "Country" that exists in df1 and a NaN for the one is missing.
I have tried .join(), .merge(), and .concat(), none of these function gave me the required result.

Comment: Can you provide the code sample with data you have tried in terms of code.

Comment: import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv('Countries of the world updated-227.csv',encoding='cp1252')
df2=pd.read_csv('Demographic-2017(GNP,political staibility)-187.csv',encoding='cp1252')  df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df=df.reset_index(drop=True);   also tried
df= pd.merge(df1,df2, on='Country',how="outer")

Answer (score 0):

For `join()`, did you make sure to select the right `how=` option?

By default, it is a `left` join, but maybe you need a `outer`, e.g.

`df1.join(how='outer')`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't match the values for the Countries !!!

Comment: Please provide a small example of a row in both columns, `df1` and `df2`, with the desired result, e.g.

`df1: Country: Spain, temp: 32, beach: yes`
`df2: Country: Spain, ....`

and

`merged ....`

Comment: df2:   Country            GNP 
0 Afghanistan     570.0
1 Albania            4320.0
2 Algeria            3960.0                                                                                        df1 :      Country  Population
0 Afghanistan 31056997
1 Albania 3581655                     
df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Country", how='outer')                                                                                                                             
        Country     Population      GNP 
0 Afghanistan 31056997.0 NaN
1 Albania 3581655.0       NaN

Comment: after merging it gives NaN for all df2 column values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Country", how='outer)
```

Comment: yes, I did. it gives NaN to all df2 column in the resulted df

Comment: @Saleh I thought you said you WANTED a  NaN

Comment: True, for countries in df1 that do not have a value in a specific column in df2, this function gives all countries in df1 NaN !!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by arranging the csv files using Excel, made country column have 223 rows for both data frams, then I used

```
    df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
    df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I got the required results.